# chromedriver auto installer in AWS Batch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium

I created a crawler, uploaded it to AWS ECR, and ran it through AWS Batch. However, I get `ValueError("No chrome executable found on PATH")`  error. In local, It works correctly

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------||
| Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                       |
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main                                                            |
|     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,                                                                                           |
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code                                                                       |
|     exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                                              |
|   File "/app/crawler/__main__.py", line 100, in <module>                                                                                 |
|     main()                                                                                                                               |
|   File "/app/crawler/decorator/crawler_decorator.py", line 13, in __call__                                                               |
|     self.func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                           |
|   File "/app/crawler/__main__.py", line 27, in main                                                                                      |
|     driver = set_driver()                                                                                                                |
|   File "/app/crawler/service/crawler.py", line 41, in set_driver                                                                         |
|     install()  # install chrome driver                                                                                                   |
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/__init__.py", line 21, in install                             |
|     chromedriver_filepath = utils.download_chromedriver(path, no_ssl)                                                                    |
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/utils.py", line 203, in download_chromedriver                 |
|     chrome_version = get_chrome_version()                                                                                                |
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/utils.py", line 109, in get_chrome_version                    |
|     path = get_linux_executable_path()                                                                                                   |
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/utils.py", line 153, in get_linux_executable_path             |
|     raise ValueError("No chrome executable found on PATH")                                                                               |
| ValueError: No chrome executable found on PATH                                                                                           |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you share your Docker file ?

Comment: I solved this by having Chrome installed when I start Github Action CD. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this alternative:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Comment: I tried it, But it returned this error `WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/105.0.5195/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127`